# Titanium Orientation Change fired for landscape whenever im leaning iPad towards myself

Tags: javascript, titanium, orientation, appcelerator

My function to get the orientation

```
function getOrientation(o) {
     switch (o) {
        case Titanium.UI.PORTRAIT: return 'portrait';
        case Titanium.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT: return 'portrait';
        case Titanium.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT: return 'landscape';
        case Titanium.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT: return 'landscape';
    }}}
```

Even listener triggered on orientationchange. This should only trigger an alert box when rotating from portrait to landscape and vise versa.

```
Ti.Gesture.addEventListener('orientationchange', function(e) {
     var orientation = getOrientation(e.orientation);

     if(orientation == 'portrait'){
         alert('portrait');
     }else if(orientation == 'landscape'){
         alert('landscape');
     }else{
         //do nothing
     }}
```

Why would I receive an alert for "landscape" whenever I am already in landscape view, and I tilt the top of my iPad towards me? It seems like that would be the 'face down' gesture. With the code above, I would expect to receive no alert. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Even I've come across this while coding according to orientation.. I guess this happens since eventlistener listens to every single acceleration change in orientation while we use iPad.